# How can I create a table in Grafana that shows Tag and min/max columns (no time)

Tags: influxdb, grafana

I'm trying to figure out how I can set up a chart/table in Grafana that will group by a tag and then show the min max in two columns. So basically 3 columns, TagName, Min, Max. I've been trying to set it up, but the Time column is always there. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't think this is currently possible. Right now, InfluxDB will always return a `time` column and Grafana tables do not allow a column to be hidden.

Comment: Ok, thanks, it looks like that yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the Table Graph type and achieve that. Something like [this](http://play.grafana.org/dashboard/db/new-features-in-v2-6?panelId=1&fullscreen)

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want it to look like, but I can't figure out how to configure that for InfluxDB, the query that's in that link doesn't work with Influx.

Comment: Here's an InfluxDB Table example - http://play.grafana.org/dashboard/db/influxdb-table?panelId=6&fullscreen&edit

Comment: Thanks, but it has the Time column in there

Comment: I like to just have the tag name and min/max columns

Comment: Grafana now appears to support hiding columns.